# how to set jpa transaction isolation to read_commited

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, seam2, transaction-isolation

I am trying to set jpa transaction isolation level to read_committed. I am using hibernate 4.1.6. there was a time we could do

```
Connection connection = session.connection();
connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.READ_COMMITTED);
```

But now that session.connection is not available any more, i am a bit confused. what is the best way of setting isolation on jpa? I am using seam 2.3.

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

apparently this is one way of doing it:

```
session.doWork(new Work() {
            @Override
            public void execute(Connection connection) throws SQLException {
                connection.setTransactionIsolation(Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
            }
        });
```

but in seam it will break if you are change the transation isolation level once the transaction started already.